# I am looking for some ideas building a product selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a product selector and this time around I would like to build a best practice so I am curious to see what other devs think is best approach. I have a product category selector that populates a product selector.

1. I don't want the product selector to show until a category is picked
2. I don't want the product selector to show if the category has only 1
   product
3. I wan't to assign the product ID to be assigned to a var if one of
   the above conditions are met.

I considered using CSS to hide the second element or, generating dynamically in JS. I created a fiddle also. Any input would be appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/simplymarkb/oa4xf2zg/

```
<label for="category" class="label">Category:</label>
    <select id="category" class="inputSelector" name="category" data-field-name="category">
    <option value="0">Select Category...</option>
</select><br><br>
<label for="productname" class="label">Product:</label>
    <select id="productname" class="inputSelector" name="productname" data-field-name="productname">
    <option value="0">Select Product...</option>
</select>



<script>
let json = [{
      "Identifier": "LOC005",
      "Category": "Soft Drink",
      "Product": "Mountain Dew",
      "ProductID": "mdew-23984987"
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "LOC005",
      "Category": "Side Dish",
      "Product": "Brown Rice",
      "ProductID": "rice-3434333"
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "LOC005",
      "Category": "Side Dish",
      "Product": "Noodles",
      "ProductID": "noodle-46ss333"
    }, 
    {
      "Identifier": "LOC005",
      "Category": "Soft Drink",
      "Product": "Sprite",
      "ProductID": "sprite-038033"
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "LOC005",
      "Category": "Pie",
      "Product": "Key Lime",
      "ProductID": "kl-39637623"
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "LOC005",
      "Category": "Pie",
      "Product": "Pumpkin",
      "ProductID": "pm-373768534"
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "LOC005",
      "Category": "Soft Drink",
      "Product": "Pepsi",
      "ProductID": "pepsi-39784862"
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "LOC005",
      "Category": "Soft Drink",
      "Product": "Dr. Pepper",
      "ProductID": "drpep-r34872"
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "LOC005",
      "Category": "Pie",
      "Product": "Blueberry",
      "ProductID": "bl-pie00012"
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "LOC005",
      "Category": "Pie",
      "Product": "Apple",
      "ProductID": "ap-pie9838732"
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "LOC005",
      "Category": "Soft Drink",
      "Product": "Coke",
      "ProductID": "coke-0e4801"
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "LOC005",
      "Category": "Pie",
      "Product": "Cherry",
      "ProductID": "ch-pie948001"
    }]

const prodCategory = [... new Set(json.map(data => data.Category))]
$.each(prodCategory, function(index, value) { 
  $("#category").append("<option class='rsource' value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
});


$("#category").change(function(){
  $("#productname").empty();
  var selValue = $(this).val();  
  let obj = json.filter(item => item.Category === selValue);
  let productval = obj.filter(item => item.Product);
  let prodcount = productval.length;

    // -- I only want to display the product selector if the category has more than one product
  if( prodcount !== 1 ){
  $.each(obj , function(index, item) {
    var Product = item.Product;
    var ProductID = item.ProductID;
    $("#productname").append("<option value='"+ProductID+"'>"+Product+"</option>");
  });
  } else {
    // something else
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer: https://jsfiddle.net/83gzbxur/5/

1. Product selector is hidden on start.
2. Product selector is shown only when conditions are met.
3. When Product selector is shown, and user select a value, the value can be retrieved and use.

```js
// ... (full code is in the fiddle)
// changes are made as follows

  $("#category").change(function(){
    // ...
    $("#selectedProduct").text('--')
    // ...
  })

  if( prodcount > 1 ){
    $("#products").show()
    // ...
  }else{
    $("#products").hide()
  }

  $("#productname").change(function(){
    $("#selectedProduct").text($("#productname").val())
  })

// ...
```